# copying xml files into text file

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to copy the contents of an xml file into txt. But everytime I open the txt file, it is showing 0. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

public class Copy
{
    private static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
        theDataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\\Users\mchowdhury\Desktop\MediaInfo.xml"); 
        StreamWriter theWriter = new StreamWriter("test.xml");
        foreach (DataRow curRow in theDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            foreach (object curObjectValue in curRow.ItemArray)
            {
                theWriter.Write(curObjectValue);
            }
        }
        theWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger to see if anything should have been written in the first place?

Comment: The debugger is not giving any errors. It builds fine.

Comment: I wrote *did you step through* with the debugger - make sure the `theWriter.Write()` line is even reached?

Comment: Then what is contained in theDataSet.Tables[0] when you view it in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to write out the data and get a sample output, try the following:

```
DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
theDataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\\Users\mchowdhury\Desktop\MediaInfo.xml");
StreamWriter theWriter = new StreamWriter("test.xml");
foreach (DataRow curRow in theDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn curCol in theDataSet.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        theWriter.Write(String.Format("{0} ", curRow[curCol]));
    }
}
theWriter.Close();
```